# tensorflow anaconda deosnt work on python

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, anaconda

I installed tensorflow with anaconda.
So I created a conda environmenent with the command

```
conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5
```

then

```
activate tensorflow
```

then

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
```

Now when I'm opening a terminal, and I'm writing `python`, then

```
import tensorflow
```

it works.
But when I try to create a .py file and write `import tensorflow` inside, then execute, it doesnt work.
What should I do ?

Comment: If someone has a solution, let me know plz, because I tried everything I could try, and nothing worked.

Comment: first post the output of `which python` from the terminal (after activating your tensorflow environment), then in the same .py file that won't import tensorflow, prepend these two lines and post the output: `import sys; print(sys.executable)`

Answer (score 0):

confirm you create your .py file in the same directory where you activate tensorflow environment.

[image]

It sould behave same as python command line in the same directory.

Comment: Yes, i confirm.

Comment: On python :
File "C:/**********/Desktop/Programme/ML/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow'  
And the terminal :
(C:\******\Anaconda3) C:\******\Desktop\Programme\ML>activate tensorflow

(tensorflow) C:\******\Desktop\Programme\ML>

Comment: you see (tensorflow) on command line right? As shown image above.

Comment: Yes ! I would like to put an image, but I don't know how .. But Yes, I see (tensorflow) before the directory

Comment: do you have any other python installation? try removing all others from PATH.

Comment: You can check with > echo %PATH%

Comment: when i write "python --version" on the anaconda prompt, it's wrote "python 3.5.4", the same version of idle i used to edit my .py file

Comment: it seems a lot of people has same issue on windows, this may help: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6136

Comment: Maybe you're right and it's a version problem.
(tensorflow) C:\Users\bromy\Desktop\Programme\ML>python --version
Python 3.5.4 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.

Comment: is that the same version of the "classic" 3.5.4 Python version ? Because I dont know what "Continuum Analytics" is.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution

When I open my text editor (for example IDLE, or Spyder) directly by the Anaconda command prompt (Write `Idle` or `Spyder` on the command prompt) it works.

But if I open my text editor by the common way, it doesn't work.
I don't really know why, because it is exactly the same version, so if someone has an explanation, feel free to give it to me !